# how to use javascript in uiwebview to get the clicked button id?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

This Time i want to know how to determine which button is click in UIWebView.....

```
    appDelegate.mystring = [[NSMutableString string]init];
    NSString *buttonstring=@"<label><input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" id=\"1\" value=\"Delete\" /></label>";

    for (int i=0; i<appDelegate.lyricsData.count; i++) {
    NSString *b= @"<br>";
    NSString *st1=[[appDelegate.lyricsData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"user_name"];
    appDelegate.mystring=[appDelegate.mystring stringByAppendingString:st1];
    appDelegate.mystring=[appDelegate.mystring stringByAppendingString:b];
    NSString *st2=[[appDelegate.lyricsData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"added_date"];
    appDelegate.mystring=[appDelegate.mystring stringByAppendingString:st2];
    appDelegate.mystring=[appDelegate.mystring stringByAppendingString:b];
    NSString *st3=[[appDelegate.lyricsData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"verse"];

    appDelegate.mystring=[appDelegate.mystring stringByAppendingString:st3];
    appDelegate.mystring=[appDelegate.mystring stringByAppendingString:buttonstring];
    appDelegate.mystring=[appDelegate.mystring stringByAppendingString:b];
    appDelegate.mystring=[appDelegate.mystring stringByAppendingString:b];



    btn_back1_en.tag = i;
    NSLog(@"%d",btn_back1_en.tag);
    [btn_back1_en addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonArray insertObject:btn_back1_en atIndex:i];
    [btn_back1_en release];     



    }
    NSLog(@"My string %@",appDelegate.mystring);

    UIWebView *mywebview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,70, 320, 240)];
    mywebview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    mywebview.opaque=NO;
    mywebview.dataDetectorTypes= UIDataDetectorTypeNone;



//  working
    NSString *htmlTempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=200; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=0; user-scalable=0;\" />  </head>         <style> *{padding:0px;margin:0px;}.wrap{width:320px;background:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;font-family:'Myriad Pro',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;}.head{  padding:15px 20px;background:url(images/bg.png) repeat-x bottom #383838;display:block; border:1px } .head-left{ float:left; width:54px;}.head-right{float:left; width:224px; clear:right; padding:0px 0px 8px 0px;} h1{ padding:0px;  font-size:16px; color:#fff;}  h2{ padding:0px; font-size:14px; color:#3a89d3;}small{ font-size:11px; color:#77c900; padding:0px;font-weight:normal;}  b{ padding:0px;font-size:16px; color:#fff; }.comments{ background:url(images/bot-line.png) no-repeat bottom left; padding:10px 0px;}.comments h1{ padding:0px;font-size:16px; color:#fff; display:inline}.comments h2{ padding:0px;font-size:14px; color:#3a89d3; display:inline; margin:0px;}.comments small{ font-size:11px; color:#77c900; padding:0px; margin:0px 0px 0px 5px; font-weight:normal; display:inline;} .comments b{ padding:0px; margin:0px 0px 5px 5px; font-size:16px; color:#fff; display:inline}   .status{padding:15px 20px;background:url(images/bg.png) repeat-x bottom #383838;display:block; margin:4px 0px; }    </style>    <body>  <div class=\"wrap\">    <div class=\"head\">    <div class=\"head-left\"><img src=\"%@\" width=\"54\" height=\"54\" /></div>    <div class=\"head-right\">  <h1>%@</h1> <h2>%@</h2> <small>on %@</small>    </div>  <br clear=\"all\" />    </div>  <div class=\"status\"><b>%@</b><div class=\"comments\"><h2>%@   </h2></div><br clear=\"all\" /> </div></div>    </body></html>",    
                                appDelegate.profilepic,appDelegate.textfield,appDelegate.username,appDelegate.added_date,appDelegate.mytextview,appDelegate.mystring];




    [mywebview loadHTMLString:htmlTempString baseURL:nil];
    mywebview.delegate=self;
```

///Button Code

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"button %@",[sender tag]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your html code use this snippet:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script>

        function iOSNativeBridge(){

            this.sendRawMessageToiOS = function(message){
//              alert(message);
                console.log("Message string to iOS: [" + message+ "]");
                var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
                iframe.setAttribute("src", "jscall://" + message);
                document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
                iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
                iframe = null;
            };

        }

        bridge = new iOSNativeBridge();


    </script>


</head>

<body>

    <a href="javascript:bridge.sendRawMessageToiOS('your message');">link</a>
    <input type="button" value="button val" name="button" id="1" onClick="javascript:bridge.sendRawMessageToiOS('your message');">

</body>


</html>
```

on native side, in uiwebview's delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSString *jsCallPrefix = @"jscall://";
    NSString *fullURLRequested = request.URL.absoluteString;

    BOOL isJavaScriptCall = ([fullURLRequested hasPrefix:jsCallPrefix]);

    if (isJavaScriptCall) {
        NSString *messageConveyed = [fullURLRequested substringFromIndex:jsCallPrefix.length];
        NSLog(@"Your message was: %@", messageConveyed);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;

}
```

With regards to the code on web side - I don't juggle with this dynamically created iframe without a reason. At first glance, it would seem sufficient just to change the location on webview's page (call document.location.href = "jscall://message"). The worst thing is, that is actually seems to work great. Unfortunately, if you take this shortcut, JS timers are messed up greatly. So take my advice - use this little, weird-looking, but *working* without any side-effects "sendRawMessageToiOS" as is :)

Little more in-depth description of what's going on in the above code:
In the web-code, whenever I want to push some data to the native-side of my app, I call sendRawMessageToiOS(dataInStringToSend). It creates an iframe, adds it to the DOM tree and sets it's location to be 
"jscall://" + dataInStringToSend
Then, as expected, the uiwebview's delegate is asked, whether or not I'm willing to start the request to download a content from a given address. I check if it's actual address (and return YES then) or only this masquerade with special "jscall://" prefix. If it is this special call, I read data that's conveyed with it, and respond NO (because webview should not try to start any real request).

Answer (score 0):

The only method I know is by implementing `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` method of `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol. The required steps are as follows:

1) Create a new class subclassed from NSObject named, say, MyWebViewDelegate. You can implement only that method:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView
       sholdStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
       navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [[request URL] relativePath]);
}
```

2) Create instance of delegate in your code and set it as a delegate of UIWebView before loading page:

```
MyWebViewDelegate *mydelegate = [[MyWebViewDelegate alloc] init];
mywebview.delegate = mydelegate;
```

3) And then try to debug. Try to put breakpoint inside ..sholdStartLoadWithRequest:.. method and ensure that you application stops in that breakpoint. Maybe you shold do a little redesign of you HTML webpage to achieve this. After that try to distinguish different buttons by value of `request` parameter.