# How to manipulate DOM in UIWebView in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am using a UIWebView in my app. I want to call a objective-c function when user clicks a link in a website in UIWebView.
Is there a way to do this? Does UIWebView allow to change it?

Comment: I just want to call a objective-c function when user click a link in UIWebView

Comment: You can do that through the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` delegate method.

Comment: See this http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/10/18/uiwebview-communication-to-objective-c/

Answer (score 7):

First hook it. `[yourwebview setDelegate:self]`

Use the following delegate method

```
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType
```

Like:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;
    //put your logic here, like 
    if (![url.scheme isEqual:@"yourscheme"]) {// or query contains or [url absolutestring] contains etc
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

If you want to manipulate DOM or call any function of UIWebView, then use:

```
[yourwebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('hello')"];
[yourwebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('#domid').hide();"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as stated in other answers, you should use webview delegate's

```
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType
```

method to smuggle some data from within the WebView. You can read my verbose answer on this topic here: [how to use javascript in uiwebview to get the clicked button id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900137/how-to-use-javascript-in-uiwebview-to-get-the-clicked-button-id/16126953#16126953)