# Swift 3 Detect when WKWebView finishes loading AJAX site

Tags: javascript, ajax, swift, webview, wkwebview

I am trying to inject some `javascript` into my `web view` when it is navigated to a product page `URL`. The website doesn't reload when navigating to different pages, so to my understanding that means it is using `Ajax.`

The problem is I need the page to be fully loaded because the purpose of the `javascript` I am using is to automatically select the size drop down.

I tried to use the [navigation delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview) but since it's not reloading between pages it only gets called when the web view is first loaded.

What I have done is setup and observer by

```
webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)
```

and check if the current URL is the URL I want to inject the `javascript` on by

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "URL" {
        guard var currentURL = webView.url?.absoluteString else { return }

        if currentURL.lowercased().range(of: "products") != nil {
           webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('size-options').selectedIndex = 1")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is it gets called right when the URL changes but not when the page finishes loading. I have got it to successfully work by adding a delay but that isn't a good solution because if the page doesn't load in time it won't work. Is there any way to know when a page like this finishes loading all its elements? The website I am working with is http://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile/#categories mobile site.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000523/how-to-manipulate-dom-in-uiwebview-in-ios