# How UIWebView detect <img src="..." /> is tapped

Tags: html, ios, image, uiwebview

I know that method below can detect a link element tap. But I want to know if the `UIView` can detect if the `img` element is tapped?

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
switch (navigationType) {
    case UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked:
        NSLog(@"link is click");
        //do something
        break;
    default:
        break;
   }

    return true;
}
```

Some html source like below:

```
<p>xxxxxxxxx</p>
<p><img src="http://imgs.ebrun.com/resources/2015_06/2015_06_16/201506167911434413787546.jpg"> </p>
<p>xxxxxxxxx。</p>
<p><img src="http://imgs.ebrun.com/resources/2015_06/2015_06_16/201506167911434413787546.jpg"> </p>
<p>xxxxxxxxx。</p>
```

Could you show me how to do it using sample code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your img tag does not have html click event. If you can make your image like below way -

```
<p>xxxxxxxxx</p>
<p><img src="http://imgs.ebrun.com/resources/2015_06/2015_06_16/201506167911434413787546.jpg" onclick="myfunction()"> </p>
<p>xxxxxxxxx。</p>
<p><img src="http://imgs.ebrun.com/resources/2015_06/2015_06_16/201506167911434413787546.jpg" onclick="myfunction()"> </p>
<p>xxxxxxxxx。</p>
```

Then you can catch your img click event within UIWebView Delegate method - shouldStartLoadWithRequest.

**Alternate possible option** -

Otherwise you have write a javascript method which dynamically add OnClick method to all IMG tags. And call this javascript method when your page load in UIWebView -

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //Execute javascript method or pure javascript if needed
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"methodName();"];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900137/how-to-use-javascript-in-uiwebview-to-get-the-clicked-button-id) answer can help you. Basically you need to wrap  tag inside  tag and handle button click event inside

```
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType
```

method