# How to identify images inside wkwebview and open it as UIImageView

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I'm doing a magazine, I need to find inside the wkvebview picture inside the tag "img" and when you click on it to expand in UIImageView (zooming image), can share in the social network. I've done a similar theme on ObjectiveC but I do not know how to do it on swift.
Thanx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect tap on image inside WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368765/detect-tap-on-image-inside-wkwebview)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861823/how-uiwebview-detect-img-src-is-click