# Detect tap on image inside WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` which has some images added with the `<img src=...>` tag, they are locally cached and I insert them into the `WKWebView`.

The images aren't being loaded from the web, with the regular `<a href...>`

As that , I want to present the tapped image to the user, but since the `WKWebView` could have a lot of images, I'm trying to detect the tap on the specific image, without success.

I tried the `decidePolicyFor` `WKNavigationDelegate` method, but anytime I tap an image no `navigationType` is called, and I don't know if I'm missing something here.

Thanks

Comment: `The images aren't being loaded from the web, with the regular <a href...>` quite confusing. `<a href...` is the tag to link something. And my question is, why don't you put a link on the images to open it in another page or even capture it on your swift/objective-c code ?

Comment: What I meant to say is that I am constructing a local `html` and in that `html` I insert images into, that are locally cached, thus the insert of the `<img>` tag, because it looks for the `html` root folder, were the images are.

There's no way for me to access the image link, because they're downloaded from a service without public access, without public link to go to.

Comment: I think you are mixing concepts. Your images can be stored locally. Your link **can** refer to a local image. And if you're building your html locally is even easier to handle it. If you can, post the code where you're building your html and we can try to make what you're aiming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How UIWebView detect <img src="..." /> is click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861823/how-uiwebview-detect-img-src-is-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have managed to surpass this issue.

Somehow I didn't knew I could create a link to a locally cached image as @GIJOW said.

After reading about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp) I have managed to display an image inside the `WKWebView` as it was before, but the whole image is now tappable because it is embeded in a `<a href>` tag as the following.

**Previous**

```
<img src=\"\(imageNameHere)\"/>
```

**After**

```
<a href=\"some_url_or_link_you_want\"><img src=\"\(imageNameHere)\"/></a>
```