# Get id of button from webview on tap in swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I have a `webview` in which I load a url coming from a backend server. There is a button in my webview on which when user tap I want to get the id of that button. How I can get the id of that button? I have used a tap gesture on which when I click I'm trying to get the id but it's not working, my code is this,

```
let webViewTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapAction(_:)))
    webViewTapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    webViewTapped.delegate = self
    webView.addGestureRecognizer(webViewTapped)

@objc func tapAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
    print("touched")

    // Get the specific point that was touched
    let point: CGPoint? = sender?.location(in: view)

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById(\"hdfUserId\").value") {(response, error) in
        if (response != nil) {
            let title = response as! String
            print(title)
        }
        // error handling
    }
}
```

This is how I'm trying to get the button id by javascript, but I'm getting fail in that

Comment: you can check this link
[get button id from webview click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900137/how-to-use-javascript-in-uiwebview-to-get-the-clicked-button-id)

Comment: i have tried this but it isn't going inside the delegate. @Samir